# jQuery display other field-values based on selecting dropdown

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

Im new to RoR , I have two models CustomerDetail and Invoice.Im populating customer_name dynamically which has created from customer_detail. And I have to display customer_id, address based on customer_name.

**JS**

here is my Jquery file

```js
$("#customer_name").prepend('<option selected="" value="Add New">Add New</option>');
 $("#customer_name").prepend("<option value='Add New'></option>").val('aaaaaaaaaa');
 $("#customer_name").on('change', function() {
   alert($('#customer_name').val());
   if ($('#customer_name').val() == 'Add New'){
     window.location.href = "/customer_details/new";
   }
 $('#cust_id').val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));

 });
```

```html
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle form-control selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="customer_name" title="nnnnnnnn"><span class="filter-option pull-left">nnnnnnnn</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
  <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="cust_id" type="text" name="invoice[customer_id]">
```

The problem is I couldn't get the customer-id based on the selection of customer name.can someone plz help me.thanks in advance!!

Comment: please use HTML code only in HTML block of code snippet.....

Comment: done..changed to html.thank u